# How to not change if an item of list which does not exist in another list

Tags: python

So we have two lists, `a`, which consists of only alphabetic characters and `b`, which is an input from the user made to a list. I'm trying to change alphabetical characters in `b` with regards to their indexes in `a`, without changing the non-alphabetical characters in users's input.

```
alphabet=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
a=input("Please enter a string: ")
b=list(a)
f=[]
for elem in b:
  if elem in alphabet:
    c=alphabet.index(elem)
    d=(len(alphabet)-c)
    e=alphabet[d-1]
    f.append(e)
mystring=''.join(f)
print(mystring)
```

I expect the output of abc123 to be zyx123

Comment: What output do you get now?

Comment: Only zyx because I define an f which doesnt have 123

Comment: You're not getting 123 because it's not in the alphabet list

Comment: you can use regex and split the field into two (numeric and alphabets), keep tuples if you want to preserve their positions and run the loops and add the lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing the else statement for when the `elem` isn't in the alphabet

```
if elem in alphabet:
    ...
else:
    f.append(elem)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `maketrans` & `str.translate` which seems to closely match what you're doing:

```
intab = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
outtab = intab[::-1]
trantab = str.maketrans(intab, outtab)

str = "abc123";
print (str.translate(trantab))

>> zyx123
```

In the above, the `outtab` variable is just the intab variable in reverse order using the python slicing syntax `[::-1]`

Maketrans converts all the characters in one list into the equivalently positioned characters in another list. Any characters not in the first list are left alone.